# How to use output for another action in one command line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have for example this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i input.mp3 -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -vf scale=nhd -r 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4
```

which suppose to take an mp3 file and a picture and combine it to one video file mp4.
Now how can i add a watermark using this command for example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5 output.mp4
```

But doing all of this in one time command and not re encoding twice or to wait for one command to finish and then do another one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i watermark.jpg -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -i input.mp3 -filter_complex [0]scale=nhd,setsar=1[v];[v][1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -r 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -fflags +shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for you answered! i will check this out. I did manage to re encode the file twice using && but i think maybe your line is better. I hope i will understand it because i am very new to ffmpeg:


ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i input.mp3 -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -vf scale=nhd -r 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4 && ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac final_output.mp4

Comment: OK it did do the job and i see that i could short the line even further and i don't see any differences. However for some reason the watermark is a little smudge and differences in size for some reason compare if i would do the twice re encoding.

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i watermark.png -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -i input.mp3 -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5,scale=nhd -r 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4

Comment: Reordered ops in edited command.

Comment: I receive an error about the setsar, you can see here: 
https://pastebin.com/iS6mUsNi Update: i remove the setsar command and it worked! do i really need it?

Comment: OK, so i added the setsar command like this setsar=1/1 and then it worked! however i don't really like it because it stretch my image. Thank you so much for you help! you solved my problem!!

ffmpeg -report -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i watermark.png -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -i input.mp3 -filter_complex [0]scale=nhd,setsar=1/1,overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -r 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -fflags +shortest output.mp4

Comment: Damn it, i didn't noticed at the time but it adds another one minute (silent) to my video :(
 Update: i removed the -r 1 command and now it is ok. so frustrating because i do want to use this command to encode the file faster.