# Using -r 1 sometime change the duration of the video file

Tags: ffmpeg

After getting help from this post 
[How to use output for another action in one command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1324583/how-to-use-output-for-another-action-in-one-command-line)

I am now facing another problem which i have encounter several times before and didn't know how to fix this. right now i am using this command line to combine an image and mp3 file to a new video file and attach watermark to it:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i watermark.png -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -i input.mp3 -filter_complex scale=nhd,overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -fflags -shortest output.mp4
```

Because this video file is only an image i want to use -r 1 to change the frame rate so the encoding will go faster. However, the result is i am having longer time period with 1 minute of silent and some players don't even read this file.

Does someone know how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a higher value `-r 5`, or if you know the output duration, in this case, 137s, add `-t 137` as an output option, removing the shortest flags.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i watermark.png -ss 00:08:02.00 -t 137 -i input.mp3 -filter_complex scale=nhd,overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -r 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -t 137 output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with every value higher than 1 and i used the -t  (duration).